# Node.js module directory structure philosophy

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory-structure

There seems to be silent agreement on directory structure of node.js. At least I couldn't find any information on official site.

From what I've understand browsing opensource projects.
Usually project has `/bin` and `/lib` directory.
`/bin` contains modules entry point[s].
`/lib` contains 'helper' code.

I guess this is based on Unix directory structure.
And it makes sense for good-old compiled programs with executables and dlls.
AFAIK `/lib` was used to share libraries between programs.

In node, however, true dependencies are in `node_modules`.
`/lib` is used for application code.
Why not use `/src`?

This model is designed from execution point of view. But all projects, I've seen, use it to structure the code under develpment too. Also I've seen github-projects where whole module is just one file in bin directory.

I'm new to node.js and would like to know how people in community came to those decisions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mentioned about `lib` and `src` happened because of node philosophy to design small modules, not only in terms of code size, but most importantly in terms of scope. This principle has its roots in unix philosophy, particularly -

- Small is beautiful.
- Make each program do one thing well.

The architecture that I follow for developing web applications is broken into `models`, `services`, `routes` and `controllers`. I use `lib` for utilities and helper functions. Also a lot of node applications are built using express which itself has minimal api. In short, it is basically a matter of choice to choose convention or configuration.

Comment: I don't follow transition between cause (modular design incentive) and effect (copycat unix directory structure). Also "configuration" for directory structure does not make sense.